# Why do I get a segmentation fault when I try to call functions from libc using CDLL in python?

Tags: python-3.x, libc

I am trying to call `srand` function from `libc` library using `CDLL`, but I got a `Segmentation fault` error before actually calling `srand`.

My code looks like this:

```
from ctypes import CDLL
import time

libc = CDLL("./libc.so.6")
libc.srand(int(time.time()))
print(libc.rand())
```

The error that I have is:

```
> python3 ex.py                    
[1]    70111 segmentation fault (core dumped)  python3 ex.py
```

I also looked at the dmesg messages:

```
[31553.069657] python3[70111]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000000000 sp 00007fffbd1f58e8 error 14 in python3.8[400000+23000]
[31553.069662] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0xffffffffffffffd6.
```

I tried also to put the full path for libc because I thought that it may be some problems with the relative path but it didn't work in this case either.

Answer (score 0):

After a few investigations and many examples of code that used CDLL I found a way to call `srand` function.

Solution:

```
from ctypes import CDLL
import time

libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
libc.srand(int(time.time()))
print(libc.rand())
```

The `libc.so.6` library must be in the same directory. I think it's a problem with relative and full path for `CDLL` but this configuration worked. I tried also with `python2` and the error was the same. I think it's a bug with `CDLL`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in default load library search path. It is defined in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. For example, on my machine:

```
cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

```
cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [automount]
# ldconfig = false
/usr/lib/wsl/lib# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
# Multiarch support
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

```
ls -lL /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2029224 Dec 16  2020 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Ok, so what should be the solution? I don't understand your answer. 
My expectation would be to put there a path to a version of libc.

Comment: The solution should be to fix `/etc/ld.so.conf` . This requires administrator permissions. I agree that one should expect path to `libc` to be there already. I'm not familiar with  your system and therefore can't explain why it is not the case. You may find more information on this subject at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html. There is also workaround - add path to `libc` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable,